# Keep IndexedDB existing ObjectStore data on upgrade

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm currently running an IndexedDB with 3 ObjectStores and the following `onupgradeneeded` function.

```
var openRequest = indexedDB.open("DB_v3", 1);
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) { 
    var thisDB = e.target.result;
    if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("ObjectStore1")) {
        var objectStore = thisDB.createObjectStore("ObjectStore1", {autoIncrement:true});
        objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", {unique:true});
    }
    if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("ObjectStore2")) {
        //create objectstore & index as above
    }
    if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("ObjectStore3")) {
        //create objectstore & index as above
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is add a 4th ObjectStore.
That for I change the version and add a 4th entry in `onupgradeneeded`.

```
var openRequest = indexedDB.open("DB_v4", 1);
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) { 

    //same as above

    if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("ObjectStore4")) {
        //create objectstore & index as above
    }
}
```

All this works fine, but the problem is, as soon as the `onupgradeneeded` gets called the already existing ObjectStores lose all their data. 

How does the `onupgradeneeded` need to look in order to keep the data of the already existing ObjectStores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`indexedDB.open("DB_v3", 1)` opens a database named DB_v3 at version 1.

`indexedDB.open("DB_v4", 1)` opens a database named DB_v4 at version 1.

Databases with different names are completely separate. You're not upgrading, you're just creating two distinct databases. If you want to upgrade an existing database, keep the name the same and increment the version. Then the old data will still be there.